# sessionStorage is cleared when you open a link on a new tab, but preserved when the link is opened on the same tab. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor tag with `target="_blank` attribute which opens an HTML page on a new tab, and that new HTML page is linked to a JS file that has the following code:

```
 if (sessionStorage.getItem("washerebefore") === "yes") {
     location.href = "url of my main page";
 }

 sessionStorage.setItem("washerebefore", "yes");
```

The idea is obviously if you click on the link, and open the new HTML page, on refresh while there, to get redirected back to the main page, and it works fine.. but only as long as the new HTML page is opened on a new tab. If I remove the `target="_blank` and have the page open on the same tab, it only works the first time, as the second time I click I get redirected instantly back, which means, the sessionStorage is not cleared. Why?

I read somewhere that sessionStorage is cleared only when you close the browser, but if that's the case, then why is it getting cleared when I open the link on a new tab?

**UPDATE**

I tried using localStorage instead, but it's still preserved despite explicitly removing the localStorage.

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("washerebefore") === "yes") {
     localStorage.removeItem("washerebefore")
     location.href = "url of my main page";
 }

 localStorage.setItem("washerebefore", "yes");
```

Why is the localStorage not removed on refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything saved in sessionStorage gets deleted when you start a new session. A session ends when the browser is closed. The session remains when the page is reloaded. A new session gets created when a new tab is opened and that's why this bug occurs.

Comment: I see. So, how do I make sure the sessionStorage is cleared when you get redirected back to the previous page? Should I just use localStorage instead and clear it on refresh?

Comment: I would use local storage because the saved data doesn't get removed when the session is closed. Therefore, you will have more control over what you want to delete and keep in local storage.

Comment: I just tried using `localStorage` instead, and just added  `removeItem` after the `location.href`, and again, it only works the first time, and then I keep getting redirected instantly. Why is it not getting removed? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please read my update? I figured why it's not removed. The issue is that, it does get removed, but then it gets saved again, but why is the second localStorage.setItem being executed at all? Since the page should get redirected, shouldn't the execution of the code stop there?

Comment: As far as I understand this the second localStorage.setItem gets executed because you exit the if statement.  Maybe try an else statement altough im uncertain if this will work

Comment: Why do you have a second local.Storage.setItem in the first place?

Comment: Where's the second one? I have only one.

Comment: I am currently struggling with with the `location.replace()`. When I use it to go to another page, the back button is still there, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Could you upload all your code? I want to test this on my local system

Comment: It's a very big code, I can't share it all. But pretty much what I'm doing is clicking on an anchor, it goes to a another HTML page, and then from that page, if I click "back" button, I am going back to the previous page, but there, I have made it so that if you get back, the page is not refreshed, but "replaced" with the same page. The purpose is to get rid of the ability of the person to click "back" and go back to the previous page, but it's not working. I can't understand why.

Comment: could you try answering my latest question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423899/i-use-location-replace-to-remove-the-page-that-i-am-leaving-from-the-doc-histo