# I use location.replace() to remove the page that I am leaving from the doc history, but when I leave, and click "forward" I get back to it. Why?

Tags: javascript

I can't give you a snippet because my code is too big, but basically I have, let's say `htmlpage1` and `htmlpage2`. When on `htmlpage1`, I click on an element, and get redirected to `htmlpage2`, on `htmlpage2`, when I click the `'back'` button on the browser, I go back to the previous `htmlpage1` page, but now what I want is when I click `forward` button, not to be able to go back again to the `htmlpage2`. How do I make this happen?

I tried adding this:

```
if(performance.navigation.type == 2 || performance.navigation.type == 0) {  location.replace("htmlpage1")
}
```

inside `htmlpage1` in order to sort of replace the current page with the same page, and my thinking was that, that would prevent the '`forward`' button from going back to '`htmlpage2`', but it's not working. It keeps going there.

I also added this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    location.replace("htmlpage1")
}
```

on the `htmlpage2` JS file. My thinking was, when you click '`back`' button, this `onbeforeunload` should be triggered, and the page should be replaced with the `htmlpage1`, thus removing it from the doc history, but again, it's not working.

Why is it not working, and how do I make it work?